# Выровнять ссылки в Navbar bootstap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap4

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInLeft" href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInLeft" href="#">Информация</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInRight" href="#">Создать</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInRight" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>  
        </nav>
</header>
```

Как мне сделать, что бы мои ссылки отображались по центру, а не слева в углу ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте класс `justify-content-center`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInLeft" href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInLeft" href="#">Информация</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInRight" href="#">Создать</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link wow backInRight" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
</nav>
```